# How to Insert into cassandra table using select from another table in cassandra?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.2

```
insert into sys.new_table select id + (select max(id) from sys.Old_table),name from sys.Old_table;
```

By this we can able to `insert` data from one table to another table in `Oracle`. How can i write this query in `Cassandra`?

```
Old_table
    ID,Case Number,Date
    8534426,HV210935,03/19/2012 12:00:00 PM
    8534427,HV210768,12/16/2011 04:30:00 AM
```

How can I `insert` data into `new_table` with `new_table.ID = Max(Old_table.ID)+Old_table.ID` and other data as on `Old_table` using `Cassandra`? I can do the insertion using above syntax in `mysql`.

```
new_table
    ID,Case Number,Date
    8534428,HV210935,03/19/2012 12:00:00 PM
    8534429,HV210768,12/16/2011 04:30:00 AM
```

Please do suggest me if this can be solved using `Spark` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using spark-cassandra connector.

Basic thing to do.

1. Get data from oldTable.
2. Get max id from the dataframe
3. create new dataframe using old dataframe. Note `.withColumn` should have same column name `id`

**Example Code using scala:**

```
val oldTable = sc.read.formt("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandr")
                 .options(Map("keyspace"->"sys","table"->"Old_table"))
                 .load()

val maxId = oldTable.select(max("id")).collect()(0).getAs[Int](0)

val newTable = oldTable.withColumn("id",lit(maxId).plus(col("id")))

newTable.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandr")
        .options(Map("keyspace"->"sys","table"->"new_table"))
        .save()
```

This is just a example code, where sc is SQLContext/HiveContext.

Based on your data size you can use `.cache()` on `oldTable`.. etc.

Modify the code based on your requirement.